# Prove $\operatorname{arccosh}'(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2 - 1}}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, inverse

I have to prove that Prove $\operatorname{arccosh}'(y) = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{y^2 - 1}}$ for all $y \in (1, \infty)$

I have to do this using the formula for differentiation of inverse functions.

$$(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}$$

For some reason the answer i end up with is

$$\operatorname{arccosh}'(y) = \cfrac{1}{y + \sqrt{y^2 - 1}}.$$

Which is obviously wrong. So how should i go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f = \cosh$. Then
$$ (f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f' \circ f^{-1}(y)} = \frac{1}{\sinh \circ \cosh^{-1} y}
$$
You know that $(\cosh)^2 - (\sinh)^2 = 1$. Hence
$$\sinh \circ \cosh^{-1} y = \sqrt{(\cosh \circ \cosh^{-1} y)^2 - 1} = \sqrt{y^2 - 1}
$$

Comment: Henry what exactly is happening in the last line? I don't get how you transform it to $y^2$?

Comment: @VictorVH Try substituting $x = \cosh^{-1} y$. Then $(\sinh x)^2 = (\cosh x)^2 - 1$.

Comment: Nvm, It's because $cosh^2(cosh^{-1}) = y^2$ right? I was confused because of the notation.

Comment: @VictorVH Yes. I don't recommend writing $\cosh^2 y$ for $(\cosh y)^2$, since that is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\operatorname{argcosh}'(y)=\frac1{\sinh(\operatorname{argcosh}y)}$$
Now $\cosh(\operatorname{argcosh}y)=y$, and $\cosh^2y-\sinh^2y=1$. Can you continue?

Comment: Can't see where you are going.

Comment: And i don't get what is happening in the very first line? Aren't you supposed to use the chain rule and differentiate argcosh y too?

Comment: In the very first line I use the formula you quote in your post for the derivative of an inverse function. The derivative of $\cosh$ is $\sinh$, isn't it? There remains to express the denominator in function of $y$. I only gave a hint to what @Henry W.  developed a moment after.